# Unity3d, Focus Cam in a rect using project matrix.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

So i'm working on this project, that require my camera to view and only view a rect area. So no matter how the camera moves, user can never see outside of the box. I attached this image below to explain my words. 
[image: aa]
I went through the Unity Camera API but didn't find anything useful, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Edit:
Turns out focus camera in a rect using projection matrix is a physically more accurate way of doing so, but i can't figure out how.

Comment: "So no matter how the camera moves, user can never see outside of the box" Unless you change the projection parameters whenever the camera moves, what you ask is basically impossible, and if you change the projection params to just show the designated area it will distort the view and I don't think that's what you want...

Comment: Unless  of course you create a very big box and place the camera inside the box.

Comment: @Gusman, what if camera is limited to, let's say we extend the left and right edge of the box, and assume they are the boundary for camera movement?

Comment: if the left-right edges are on plane X, what are the limits for Y and Z? Unless you restrict (and a lot) all the axes, that will not work.

Comment: @Gusman, i just updated the images, is that what you mean? If so how should i achieve this? Is Projection matrix that i should be setting?

Comment: It's not _"impossible"_.  All you need do is change the focal length. As the camera moves away, increase the FL, causing a telephoto effect.  As you move in, reduce the FL.  If you are really worried, create clip planes

Comment: awesome so what if cam is move left and right?

Comment: You want your camera to be always looking at the centre of the box,  irrespective of camera position

Comment: by center of the box, do you mean the center of that 3d box or the center of the rect?

Comment: and if you dont mind, why center?

Comment: @MickyD, I just got time to try that out, center of the 3d box, It worked quite well, thank you!

Comment: @libra Is the question resolved?

Comment: @SamyBencherif actually not, turns out setting projection matrix would be a more physically accurate to do this, i'm updating the question.

Comment: @libra As Gusman said, that will cause weird distortions. I'm fairly certain the only way to do this while avoiding crazy warping is by constraining the camera's movement. Are you sure you want to take the projection matrix route?

Comment: thx, turns out the distortion is what i need, found a few posts in unity forum, saying that the projection matrix should be used!

Comment: This may be helpful: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/MirrorReflection3 (particularly the second to last function)

Comment: @SamyBencherif, thank you so much!, i think this is what I am going for, would you like to move this answer section?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146138/discussion-between-samy-bencherif-and-libra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Samy Bencherif for providing the Resource.

The code here have a similar feature that should do the job, I will do more digging into it and post a more complete solution once I got time.

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/MirrorReflection4

**Edit**

I found my solution here. By hpJohn in Unity Forum:

```
public Transform[] Corners;
public Transform lookTarget;
public bool drawNearCone, drawFrustum;

Camera theCam;

void Start () {
    theCam = camera;
}

void Update () {
    Vector3 pa, pb, pc, pd;
    pa = Corners[0].position; //Bottom-Left
    pb = Corners[1].position; //Bottom-Right
    pc = Corners[2].position; //Top-Left
    pd = Corners[3].position; //Top-Right

    Vector3 pe = theCam.transform.position;// eye position

    Vector3 vr = ( pb - pa ).normalized; // right axis of screen
    Vector3 vu = ( pc - pa ).normalized; // up axis of screen
    Vector3 vn = Vector3.Cross( vr, vu ).normalized; // normal vector of screen

    Vector3 va = pa - pe; // from pe to pa
    Vector3 vb = pb - pe; // from pe to pb
    Vector3 vc = pc - pe; // from pe to pc
    Vector3 vd = pd - pe; // from pe to pd

    float n = -lookTarget.InverseTransformPoint( theCam.transform.position ).z; // distance to the near clip plane (screen)
    float f = theCam.farClipPlane; // distance of far clipping plane
    float d = Vector3.Dot( va, vn ); // distance from eye to screen
    float l = Vector3.Dot( vr, va ) * n / d; // distance to left screen edge from the 'center'
    float r = Vector3.Dot( vr, vb ) * n / d; // distance to right screen edge from 'center'
    float b = Vector3.Dot( vu, va ) * n / d; // distance to bottom screen edge from 'center'
    float t = Vector3.Dot( vu, vc ) * n / d; // distance to top screen edge from 'center'

    Matrix4x4 p = new Matrix4x4(); // Projection matrix
    p[0, 0] = 2.0f * n / ( r - l );
    p[0, 2] = ( r + l ) / ( r - l );
    p[1, 1] = 2.0f * n / ( t - b );
    p[1, 2] = ( t + b ) / ( t - b );
    p[2, 2] = ( f + n ) / ( n - f );
    p[2, 3] = 2.0f * f * n / ( n - f );
    p[3, 2] = -1.0f;

    theCam.projectionMatrix = p; // Assign matrix to camera

    if ( drawNearCone ) { //Draw lines from the camera to the corners f the screen
        Debug.DrawRay( theCam.transform.position, va, Color.blue );
        Debug.DrawRay( theCam.transform.position, vb, Color.blue );
        Debug.DrawRay( theCam.transform.position, vc, Color.blue );
        Debug.DrawRay( theCam.transform.position, vd, Color.blue );
    }

    if ( drawFrustum ) DrawFrustum( theCam ); //Draw actual camera frustum

}

Vector3 ThreePlaneIntersection ( Plane p1, Plane p2, Plane p3 ) { //get the intersection point of 3 planes
    return ( ( -p1.distance * Vector3.Cross( p2.normal, p3.normal ) ) +
            ( -p2.distance * Vector3.Cross( p3.normal, p1.normal ) ) +
            ( -p3.distance * Vector3.Cross( p1.normal, p2.normal ) ) ) /
        ( Vector3.Dot( p1.normal, Vector3.Cross( p2.normal, p3.normal ) ) );
}

void DrawFrustum ( Camera cam ) {
    Vector3[] nearCorners = new Vector3[4]; //Approx'd nearplane corners
    Vector3[] farCorners = new Vector3[4]; //Approx'd farplane corners
    Plane[] camPlanes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes( cam ); //get planes from matrix
    Plane temp = camPlanes[1]; camPlanes[1] = camPlanes[2]; camPlanes[2] = temp; //swap [1] and [2] so the order is better for the loop

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        nearCorners[i] = ThreePlaneIntersection( camPlanes[4], camPlanes[i], camPlanes[( i + 1 ) % 4] ); //near corners on the created projection matrix
        farCorners[i] = ThreePlaneIntersection( camPlanes[5], camPlanes[i], camPlanes[( i + 1 ) % 4] ); //far corners on the created projection matrix
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        Debug.DrawLine( nearCorners[i], nearCorners[( i + 1 ) % 4], Color.red, Time.deltaTime, false ); //near corners on the created projection matrix
        Debug.DrawLine( farCorners[i], farCorners[( i + 1 ) % 4], Color.red, Time.deltaTime, false ); //far corners on the created projection matrix
        Debug.DrawLine( nearCorners[i], farCorners[i], Color.red, Time.deltaTime, false ); //sides of the created projection matrix
    }
}
```